# Different Master page only for a particular user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint website, and the Master page looks different only for a particular user. This user has the same permissions as other users. when an other user logs in and tries in the same system, the Master page/ Page layout is coming properly. Is it possible for the website to pick up a different Master page only for a particular user.

Comment: other user logs tries in the same system with same browser or different browser?

Comment: try clearing browser cache

Comment: are all files css and javascript files checked in/published ? Is the page layout and masterpage published ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.. The master page was not published. so the site owners and normal users were seeing different design on master page. Once i published the master page all the users are able to view the same page.